# textRecipent is not deleting the removed item from the printed receipent

Tags: python, tkinter

I am tring to create a pos for a clinic
this is my 1st project
when I remove item from the receipent frame using the remove button then print
the printed file still appear the deleted items

I think the mistake is in the deleted function but iam not sure what to do ??
this is my code :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk
import os
import tkinter.messagebox
import tempfile



class pos:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry('1350x700+0+0')
        self.root.title('Point of sale ')
        self.root.configure(background='lightblue')
        self.input_value=True



        global operator
        operator=''
        change_input=StringVar()
        cash_input=StringVar()
        tax_input=StringVar()
        subtotal_input=StringVar()
        total_input=StringVar()
        item=StringVar()
        qty=StringVar()
        amount=StringVar()
        choice=StringVar()
        cash_input=StringVar()

        mainFrame=Frame(self.root,bg='lightblue')
        mainFrame.grid(padx=8,pady=5)

        buttonFrame=Frame(mainFrame,bd=5,width=1350,
            height=160,padx=4,pady=4,bg='lightblue',relief=RIDGE)
        buttonFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        dataFrame=Frame(mainFrame,bd=5,width=1300,
            height=400,padx=5,pady=4,bg='lightblue',relief=RIDGE)
        dataFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        dataFrameLeftCover=LabelFrame(dataFrame,bd=5,width=800,
            height=300,padx=5,pady=2,bg='lightblue',relief=RIDGE,
            font=('arial',14,'bold'),text=' Point of Sale')
        dataFrameLeftCover.pack(side=LEFT)

        changeButtonFrame=Frame(dataFrameLeftCover,bd=5,width=300,
            height=460,padx=5,pady=5,bg='white',relief=RIDGE,)
        changeButtonFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

        receipetFrame=Frame(dataFrameLeftCover,bd=5,width=200,
            height=400,padx=5,pady=5,bg='white',relief=RIDGE,)
        receipetFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)

        clinicItemFrame=LabelFrame(dataFrame,bd=5,width=450,
            height=300,padx=5,pady=2,bg='lightblue',relief=RIDGE,
            font=('arial',12,'bold'),text=' Items')
        clinicItemFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)

        calFrame=Frame(buttonFrame,bd=5,width=432,
            height=140,padx=5,pady=4,bg='lightblue',relief=RIDGE)
        calFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        changeFrame=Frame(buttonFrame,bd=5,width=500,
            height=140,padx=5,pady=4,bg='lightblue',relief=RIDGE)
        changeFrame.grid(row=0,column=1)

        removeFrame=Frame(buttonFrame,bd=5,width=400,
            height=140,padx=5,pady=4,bg='lightblue',relief=RIDGE)
        removeFrame.grid(row=0,column=2)


        #=================== Calculate widget =================

        self.lblSubTotal=Label(calFrame,bd=5,padx=5,pady=4,width=8,
            font=('arial',14,'bold'),
            text='Sub Total',relief=RIDGE)
        self.lblSubTotal.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.txtSubTotal=Entry(calFrame,bd=5,font=('arial',14,
            'bold'),
            text='Sub Total',relief=RIDGE,
            textvariable=subtotal_input)
        self.txtSubTotal.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)
                      #========================#

        self.lblTax=Label(calFrame,bd=5,padx=5,pady=4,width=8,
            font=('arial',14,'bold'),
            text='Tax',relief=RIDGE)
        self.lblTax.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.txtTax=Entry(calFrame,bd=5,font=('arial',14,
            'bold'),
            text='Tax',relief=RIDGE,
            textvariable=tax_input)
        self.txtTax.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
                      #========================#

        self.lblTotal=Label(calFrame,bd=5,padx=5,pady=4,width=8,
            font=('arial',14,'bold'),
            text='Total',relief=RIDGE)
        self.lblTotal.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.txtTotal=Entry(calFrame,bd=5,font=('arial',14,
            'bold'),
            text='Total',relief=RIDGE,
            textvariable=total_input)
        self.txtTotal.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
                      
#=================== [Function calls] =================

        def iprint():
            q=self.textReceipt.get('1.0',END)
            print(q)
            filename=tempfile.mktemp('.txt', )
            open(filename,'w',encoding='utf-8').write(q)
            os.startfile(filename,'print')

        def btnClearDisplay():
            global operator
            operator=''
            change_input.set('')
            cash_input.set('0')
            tax_input.set('')
            subtotal_input.set('')
            total_input.set('')
            for selected_item in self.pos_record.get_children():
                self.pos_record.delete(selected_item)
                

        def delete():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax)/100)))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)+((ItemCost*Tax)/100)))))
                selected_item=(self.pos_record.selection())
                self.pos_record.delete(selected_item)
                self.textReceipt.delete(1.0,'end-1')
                giveChange()

        def giveChange():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            cashInput=float(cash_input.get())
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost +=float(self.pos_record.item(child,'values')[2])
            change_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(cashInput-((ItemCost)+(ItemCost*Tax)/100))))
            if (cash_input.get=='0'):
                change_input.set('')
                method_of_pay()

        def method_of_pay():
            if (choice.get()=='Cash'):
                self.txtCost.focus()
                cash_input.set('')
            if (choice.get()==''):
                cash_input.set('0')
                change_input.set('')

        def change():
            change_input.set('')
            cash_input.set('0')

#=================== ChangeFrame widget =================

        self.lblMOP=Label(changeFrame,bd=5,padx=5,pady=4,
            font=('arial',14,'bold'),
            text='Method of Payment',relief=RIDGE)
        self.lblMOP.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        self.cboMOP=ttk.Combobox(changeFrame,width=36,
            font=('arial',14,'bold'),state='readonly',
            textvariable=choice,justify=RIGHT)

        self.cboMOP['values']=('','Cash','Visa Card' , 'Master Card')
        self.cboMOP.current(0)
        self.cboMOP.grid(row=0,column=1)
                      #========================#

        self.lblCost=Label(changeFrame,bd=5,padx=5,pady=4,
        width=8,font=('arial',14,'bold'),
            text='Cost',relief=RIDGE)
        self.lblCost.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.txtCost=Entry(changeFrame,bd=5,font=('arial',14,
            'bold'),textvariable=cash_input,relief=RIDGE)
        self.txtCost.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
        self.txtCost.insert(0,'0')
                      #========================#

        self.lblChange=Label(changeFrame,bd=5,padx=5,pady=4,width=8,
            font=('arial',14,'bold'),
            text='Change',relief=RIDGE)
        self.lblChange.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.txtChange=Entry(changeFrame,bd=5,font=('arial',14,
            'bold'),
            text='Total',relief=RIDGE,
            textvariable=change_input)
        self.txtChange.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W)
                      
#=================== Buttons pay ,print, remove widget =================

        self.btnPay=Button(removeFrame,bd=5,
            width=10,height=1,font=('arial',15,'bold'),
            text='Pay',relief=RIDGE,command=giveChange)
        self.btnPay.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=4)

        self.btnPrint=Button(removeFrame,bd=5,
            width=10,height=1,font=('arial',15,'bold'),
            text='Print',relief=RIDGE,command=iprint)
        self.btnPrint.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=4)

        self.btnReset=Button(removeFrame,bd=5,
            width=10,height=1,font=('arial',15,'bold'),
            text='Reset',relief=RIDGE,command=btnClearDisplay)
        self.btnReset.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=4)

        self.btnRemoveItem=Button(removeFrame,bd=5,
            width=10,height=1,font=('arial',15,'bold'),
            text='Remove Item',relief=RIDGE,command=delete)
        self.btnRemoveItem.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=5,pady=4)

#=================== Buttons Calculate =================

        self.btn1=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(1),
            text='1',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.btn2=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(2),
            text='2',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn2.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.btn3=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(3),
            text='3',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn3.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.btn4=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(4),
            text='4',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn4.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.btn5=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(5),
            text='5',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn5.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.btn6=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(6),
            text='6',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn6.grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.btn7=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(7),
            text='7',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn7.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.btn8=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(8),
            text='8',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn8.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.btn9=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(9),
            text='9',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn9.grid(row=2,column=2)

        self.btn0=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick(0),
            text='0',relief=RAISED)
        self.btn0.grid(row=3,column=1)

        self.btnC=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),
            text='C',relief=RAISED,command=change)
        self.btnC.grid(row=3,column=0)

        self.btndot=Button(changeButtonFrame,bd=8,
            font=('arial',20,'bold'),command=lambda:btnClick('.'),
            text='.',relief=RAISED)
        self.btndot.grid(row=3,column=2)

#=================== Function  ===========================

        def Clinic_1():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف باطنة','1','100'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف باطنة'+'\t\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'100'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax)/100)))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)+(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))


        def Clinic_2():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف اطفال','1','100'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف اطفال'+'\t\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'100'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_3():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف نسا','1','140'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف نسا'+'\t\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'140'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_4():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف رمد','1','120'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف رمد'+'\t\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'120'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_5():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف انف و اذن','1','120'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف انف و اذن'+'\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'120'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_6():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف جلدية','1','100'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف جلدية'+'\t\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'100'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_7():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف عظام','1','100'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف عظام'+'\t\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'100'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_8():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف طوارئ','1','100'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف طوارئ'+'\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'100'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_9():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف اسنان','1','35'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف اسنان'+'\t\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'35'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_10():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('كشف علاج طبيعي','1','100'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('كشف علاج طبيعي'+'\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'100'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_11():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('تحاليل طبية ','1','00'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('تحاليل طبية '+'\t\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'00'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))

        def Clinic_12():
            ItemCost=0
            Tax=10
            self.pos_record.insert('',END,values=('خدمات','1','00'))
            self.textReceipt.insert(END,('خدمات'+'\t\t\t\t'+'1'+'\t\t\t'+'00'+'\n'))
            for child in self.pos_record.get_children():
                ItemCost += float(self.pos_record.item(child,
                    'values')[2])
                subtotal_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(ItemCost)))
                tax_input.set(str('$%.2f'%((ItemCost*Tax/100))))
                total_input.set(str('$%.2f'%(((ItemCost)
                    +(ItemCost*Tax/100)))))


        
        
        def btnClick(numbers):
            global operator
            operator=operator+str(numbers)
            cash_input.set(operator)

#=================== TreeView=text=widged =================

        scroll_y = Scrollbar(receipetFrame,orient=VERTICAL)
        self.pos_record=ttk.Treeview(receipetFrame,height=20,
            columns=('Item','Qty','Amount')
            ,yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
        scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

        self.pos_record.heading('Item',text='Item')
        self.pos_record.heading('Qty',text='Qty')
        self.pos_record.heading('Amount',text='Amount')

        self.pos_record['show']='headings'

        self.pos_record.column('Item',width=120)
        self.pos_record.column('Qty',width=100)
        self.pos_record.column('Amount',width=100)


        self.pos_record.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        self.pos_record.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>')
        self.textReceipt =Text(receipetFrame,
            width=80,height=1,font=('arial',5,'bold'))
        self.textReceipt.pack()
        self.textReceipt.insert(END,'Item\t\t\t\t Qty\t\t\t Amount\t\n')


        



#=================== Buttons Calculate =================


        self.btnClinic1=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة الباطنة',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_1)
        self.btnClinic1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.btnClinic2=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة الاطفال',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_2)
        self.btnClinic2.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.btnClinic3=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة النسا',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_3)
        self.btnClinic3.grid(row=4,column=0)

        self.btnClinic4=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة الرمد',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_4)
        self.btnClinic4.grid(row=3,column=0)

        self.btnClinic5=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة الانف و لاذن',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_5)
        self.btnClinic5.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.btnClinic6=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة الجلدية',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_6)
        self.btnClinic6.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.btnClinic7=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة العظام',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_7)
        self.btnClinic7.grid(row=4,column=1)

        self.btnClinic8=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة الطوارئ',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_8)
        self.btnClinic8.grid(row=3,column=1)

        self.btnClinic9=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة الاسنان',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_9)
        self.btnClinic9.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.btnClinic10=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='عيادة العلاج الطبيعي',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_10)
        self.btnClinic10.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.btnClinic11=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='معمل التحاليل الطبية',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_11)
        self.btnClinic11.grid(row=5,column=1)

        self.btnClinic12=Button(clinicItemFrame,bd=5,
            text='خدمات',relief=RIDGE,width=15,command=Clinic_12)
        self.btnClinic12.grid(row=5,column=0)









if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    application=pos(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please [edit] your question to include a [mre] and format it as code

Comment: You have posted a LOT of code. Can you reduce the problem down to a simple, short example that exhibits the same problem that you are experiencing?